# Will living 50 miles away from one's sponsored job affect an application to settle in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

My wife and I have been living and working in the UK for over five years on Tier 2 visas.  Now we plan to apply to settle in the UK.

Will our application be affected negatively if we move to a location 50 miles away from the job my wife was sponsored for?  The information on applying to settle states as a requirement:

> your employer (sponsor) still needs you for your job

So presumably intent to continue the same employment is part of the decision process.

The circumstances are that my wife is on maternity leave, and we want to temporarily move to a location near my work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It's your commute, and there may very well be case workers who have longer ones than that to get to their job. If they ask, you can explain it, but that is a readily defensible situation.

The scenarios that normally raise eyebrows are ones where the immigrant has never lived close to their work and lives hundreds of miles away. And even that is drawing less scrutiny these days for certain professions where the work doesn't necessarily require on-site presence.

Comment: Indeed, while this is true, the question is not even about a commute; it's about a temporary relocation during a period of leave, which is even easier to justify.